# Connecting to Google Analytics Reporting API

Tags: c#, google-api, google-analytics-api

I am trying to connect to the Google Analytics reporting API to get basic pageview stats. Im trying to follow this tutorial (http://www.arboundy.com/2012/04/getting-started-with-google-analytics-in-c/). I'm having trouble setting the correct bits to get a successful auth as it seems google has changed the APIs a lot lately so the original config doesn't seem to work.

Heres what I currently have:

```
        Service = new AnalyticsService("MyDemoApp");
        Service.setUserCredentials("user@gmail.com", "password");

        AccountQuery AccountsQuery = new AccountQuery("https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga"/*Not sure what goes here this gives a 400*/);
        AccountFeed AccountsFeed = Service.Query(AccountsQuery); // 400 error here
```

Any ideas how to connect to this via the V3 api (which appears to be the one I got from NuGet)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this must work for u in c#. (i have tried and worked)

```
    string username = "youremailuser@domain.com";
    string pass = "yourpassword";
    string gkey = "?key=YourAPIkEY";

    string dataFeedUrl = "https://www.google.com/analytics/feeds/data" + gkey;
    string accountFeedUrl = "https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/management/accounts" + gkey;

    AnalyticsService service = new AnalyticsService("WebApp");
    service.setUserCredentials(username, pass);

    DataQuery query1 = new DataQuery(dataFeedUrl);


    query1.Ids = "ga:12345678";
    query1.Metrics = "ga:visits";
    query1.Sort = "ga:visits";

    query1.GAStartDate = new DateTime(2012, 1, 2).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
    query1.GAEndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    query1.StartIndex = 1;        

    DataFeed dataFeedVisits = service.Query(query1);

    foreach (DataEntry entry in dataFeedVisits.Entries)
    {
        string st = entry.Title.Text;
        string ss = entry.Metrics[0].Value;
        visits = ss;
    }
```

for more details [Read data from Google data API](http://tilr.blogspot.com/2013/02/read-data-from-google-data-api-when-you.html)

Comment: thanks for that example but im having a little trouble getting it going. I cant seem to find anywhere to generate an API key for google services as everything seems to use OAuth 2.0, (since v3 of the api it appears). Im sure your code works if you have an API key but im not sure how to obtain one

Comment: To get your API Key do this:
Follow the instructions on https://developers.google.com/analytics/resources/articles/gdata-migration-guide (Create a Project in the Google APIs Console) to generate your key.

Comment: Cool thanks found the key and everything seems to be working as expected now

Comment: The api is on version 3 now. Does that mean that older versions will stop working altogether??

Comment: @user20358 dd u Create a Project in the Google APIs Console ?